# Elasticsearch filter after aggregation

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

I want convert sql query to ES query.

This is my sql query

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT order_number, MIN(log_datetime) as log_datetime 
FROM t_log 
WHERE mall_id='amazon' AND action_name='order_register' AND log_level='3' 
GROUP BY order_number) as temp
WHERE log_datetime BETWEEN '2018-11-16 00:00:00' AND '2018-11-16 23:59:59';
```

and my es query

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "mall_id": "devsdkwms1001"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "action_name": "order_register"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "log_level": 3
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "temp": {
      "range": {
        "field": "log_datetime",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": "2018-11-16 00:00:00",
            "to": "2018-11-16 23:59:59"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "result": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "order_number",
            "size": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My es query.. it doesn't work properly.
I can't find a way to filter the aggregate results in Elastic Search.
Only can aggregate after filter.
Is there any way? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want filter agg result take a look to bucker selector:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html

Comment: why cant I select bucket on terms aggregation when its a non digit item? I am getting terms of string ,so cant select bucket based on it

Comment: Hi, not sure to understand, have you an example? / open a new subject

Comment: ,Hii, Suppose a term aggregation is returning name of places in its key.And I want to filter out only the buckets which has "India" in it...It seems its not possible.We can only filter out items that returns digits etc where we can compare using less than or morethan or equals etc.